# How to find out what kind of ELF files a linux system can execute?

Tags: linux, executable, elf

I want to know what kind of ELF executables can my linux system execute without bruteforcing until this error disappears:

```
Failed to execute process: '<executable>' the file could not be run by the operating system.
```

So, is there a command where it shows the kind of ELF executables it can run, in the form of the output of the `file`
command, e.g:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=7317445698b9e68d63fcc34a2ad3be266953ed19, for GNU/Linux 4.4.0, strippe
```

‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

Comment: What is the output from `uname -a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know what kind of ELF executables can my linux system execute

Your system can execute ELF binaries compiled *for your target architecture*, which you can find by running `uname -a`.

A typical output would look like this:

```
Linux <hostname> 5.19.11-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.19.11-1 (2022-10-31) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

You can see that this is an `x86_64` host. It can run `x86_64` and `i*86` ELF executables.

Since you *do* have an `x86_64` executable according the output from `file`, it must be that you do *not* have an `x86_64` host.